# Structure for Python app that includes a webhook (bottle) and API calls (cron jobs) in OpenShift

Tags: python, cron, openshift, bottle

I've created an application that is composed of two parts: a bottle webserver that is used as a webhook and a simple script that should run periodically to retrieve data from an API.

My code is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/bani/ninja): [callbacks.py](https://github.com/bani/ninja/blob/7a29f1a0acbaefabf8fe495b230f231712f181b6/callbacks.py) is the webhook and [temperature.py](https://github.com/bani/ninja/blob/7a29f1a0acbaefabf8fe495b230f231712f181b6/temperature.py) is the script. Both use a method from [universal.py](https://github.com/bani/ninja/blob/7a29f1a0acbaefabf8fe495b230f231712f181b6/universal.py).

I'm hosting my application in OpenShift with two cartridges: Python 2.7 and Cron 1.4.

I was able to make the webhook run with the following folder structure:

```
bottle
+-README.md
+-app.py.disabled
+-data (empty folder)
+-libs (empty folder)
+-setup.py
+-setup.pyc
+-setup.pyo
+-wsgi
+---application
+---mybottleapp.py (corresponds to callback.py)
+---static (folder with just a README file)
+---universal.py
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to include the API script part there, in particular where to add the files for the script, for the two libraries that it needs (requests and ninja), and if possible to share the universal.py with the webhook.

Any help is appreciated.